# Перезапуск функции в случае вознекновения ошибки TeleBot

Tags: python-3.7

вот собственно код

## def get_weight(message):

```
global weight
try:
    weight = float ( message.text ) #Получаю длинну заказа
except:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Не верный тип данных! Введите заного число")   # вот тут

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Какова высота данного заказа?")
bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_height)
```

#
Собственно если пользователь ввёл не число , а слово, то бот просто прекращает работать. Моя задача, чтобы Написало "Не верный тип данных! Введите заного число"

Жду ваших предложение. У самого получается бесконечно цикл получается

Comment: Попробуйте ‘’try: … expect TypeError:…’’ и зачем делать переменную глобальной, в приведенном вами коде «глобальность» не нужна

Comment: Это лишь часть кода

Answer (score 0):

Если не работает штатный способ, то создадим свой, почему бы и нет?:

```
_float = “float”
weight_value = message.text
weight_type = type(weight_value)
if _float in str(weight_type):
   #если weight - float
else:
   #если weight что - то ещё
```

Или “if” можно уместить в одну строку

```
is_weight_float = [True if _float in str(weight_type) else False]
```

Думаю, понятно, что если «is_weight_float» принимает два значения True - переменная «weight» - float, False - переменная “weight” другого типа.